# Windows 7 not showing connected android device's internal storage in explorer

Tags: windows-7, usb, android

Hi Every one my windows 7 machine suddenly stop showing internal storage for my android device. My device is properly connected to my machine and its working properly. Only thing it windows 7 not showing its internal storage.My machine is kind of restricted profile machine. But I have root access. I dont know what happened in regedit.It shows USB drives like external storage devices but not showing my android device internal storage. I tried to enable via computer management and portable devices and from there tried to enable it. But its not working for me. I checked with other machine on which it is working fine.I am using MTP mode only.

Need Some help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When I upgraded my Nexus 5 to Android 6.0 I've noticed the same thing.

There's simply a new USB mode, obviously set by default: charge only.

You should have a notification for that. Tap it and you should be able to re-enable MTP mode to show the device contents as an USB device.

Comment: in my scenario I am not upgrading my device and also I have connected device in MTP mode itself. But still it is not showing in explorer.

Comment: @nilkash Have you tried switching mode back and forth? How about reinstalling/changing drivers? Or is the device not even shown in Device Manager?

Comment: yup I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Delete/uninstall the driver instead of just disable it.
2. Connect the phone and try.
3. If the phone is not recognized do below.
4. Reinstall the most up to date driver.
5. Reboot both phone and PC and try again.

The problem may be happening because you've connected another phone. This is why the driver needs to be deleted.